# How can I set a matching message?

Tags: java, android

I'm just building a simple DICE app. But I want to add one more extra functionality. When Both numbers are the matched, the user getting a Message. E.g >> Number Match. Please look at my **code** this 
[image: Screenshot]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView leftDice = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_leftDice);
        final ImageView rightDice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_rightDice);

        final int[] diceArray = {
                R.drawable.dice1,
                R.drawable.dice2,
                R.drawable.dice3,
                R.drawable.dice4,
                R.drawable.dice5,
                R.drawable.dice6
        };

        Button rollButton;
        rollButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);

        rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

                int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);

                leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);
                number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
                rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something called `Toast`, just add this after checking if the both dices are matched:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will add a message on the screen for some time.

And your message (`Toast`) will look something like this: 
[image]

So your whole code for `MainActivity` will be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView leftDice = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_leftDice);
        final ImageView rightDice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_rightDice);

        final int[] diceArray = {
                R.drawable.dice1,
                R.drawable.dice2,
                R.drawable.dice3,
                R.drawable.dice4,
                R.drawable.dice5,
                R.drawable.dice6
        };

        Button rollButton;
        rollButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rollButton);

        rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

                int numberForLeftDice = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
                int numberForRightDice = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);

                leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[numberForLeftDice]);
                rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[numberForRightDice]);

                if (numberForLeftDice == numberForRightDice) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mate. It worked. That's what I'm looking for. But I want the message when both numbers should be matched. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick function you can do sth like that:

```
Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

int numberLeft = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[numberLeft]);

int numberRight = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(6);
rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[numberRight]);

if(numberLeft == numberRight){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Same number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This code will give 2 errors-> line 4: undefined symbol "number", line 7: undefined symbol "number"

Comment: Hello Matze, I applied your code but it showed error.

Comment: Hello @HarshitSeksaria Thank you Mate. It worked. But I want the message when both numbers should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using `AlertDialog` or `Toast`

For `AlertDialog`
User can Click, **Yes** Or **No** Or any else (As per your requirements)

However For `Toast`
Just like a pop up message that pop up but without any clickable ability
It is just for showing the message.